# Power rule step. Where does equation of the difference of two numbers raised to the same power come from?

Tags: calculus

I am looking at a proof of the power rule and I see this:

$x^n - a^n = (x-a)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}*a + {...} + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1})$

Where does this come from?

It's used in this proof which I'm trying to understand:

[image]

What is it called?

Comment: For "what's it called", no particular name, you could say "factorisation of a difference of $n$th powers".  For "where does it come from", try the [history of maths SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well, it's like the difference of perfect squares or difference of perfect cubes.  You should know that $x^2-a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)$ and $x^3-a^3 = (x-a)(x^2+xa+a^2)$

Comment: Hint: $x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}*a + {...} + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1}$ is the sum of a geometric progression. When I was at school, we studied those in the lead-up to limits and calculus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117660/proving-xn-yn-x-yxn-1-xn-2-y-x-yn-2-yn-1)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know that it has a name other than [difference of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum/difference_of_two_nth_powers) [identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Sum_and_difference_of_powers). It follows for $\,z = \dfrac{x}{a}\,$ from the even simpler:

$$
\begin{align}
z^n-1 &= (z^n\color{red}{-z^{n-1}})+ (\color{red}{z^{n-1}}-\color{blue}{z^{n-2}})+ \ldots +(\color{blue}{z}-1) \\
 &= z^{n-1}(z-1) + z^{n-2}(z-1)+\ldots+ 1 \cdot (z-1) \\
 &= (z-1)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+\ldots+1)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$a $ is a root of $f (x)=x^n-a^n$...  hence $(x-a)| f (x) $...  this follows from  the *polynomial factor theorem*

It remains to find the polynomial that is $\frac {x^n-a^n}{x-a} $

This can be done by synthetic division