# How to picture $x^n−y^n \equiv (x−y)(x^{n−1}+x^{n−2}y+...+xy^{n−2}+y^{n−1})$?

Tags: visualization

Many students fail to intuit [$x^n−y^n \equiv (x−y)(x^{n−1}+x^{n−2}y+...+xy^{n−2}+y^{n−1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/117676) , as substantiated by the [glut](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4193590/1211588) of [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1812555). How can students pictorialize it?

[After substituting $z = \dfrac xy$, this identity follows from $z^n−1 \equiv (z−1)(z^{n−1}+z^{n−2}+...+z+1)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2601906)

I need to motivate this identity from Michael Spivak, *Calculus* (4 edn 2008), p. 13, Problem 1(v). But I found no picture proof for this in Roger B. Nelson's [*Proofs without Words* (1993),

*Proofs without Words II* (2000), or *Proofs without Words III* (2015)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3457754).

Comment: $z^n−1 = (z−1)(z^{n−1}+z^{n−2}+...+z+1)$ is basically partial sum of geometric series, if that helps.

Comment: I understand that you know it, but I'm suggesting looking at this through lens of geometric sequences instead of "random" algebraic identity.

Comment: There is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1990137/122131) in special case when $z=2$.

Comment: There is also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROovDaRQVl0) YouTube video.

Comment: For $n=2,3$, it can be visualized with differences of areas/volumes.

Comment: There is this picture proof by Roger Nelson: https://maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/proof-without-words-geometric-series

Comment: @MathSensei That PDF pictorializes Geometric Series, not this identity.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks. I know. Can this identity $\forall \; n \ge 4$ be visualized with differences of HyperAreas of HyperVolumes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a tabular format to display the result of expanding something of the form $(x - y)z$ as $xz -yz$? Thus:
$$
(x−y)(x^{n−1}+x^{n−2}y+{}...{}+xy^{n−2}+y^{n−1}) ={}\\ \\
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
&[(x^n + {}&x^{n-1}y + {}& x^{n-2}y^2 + {}& \ldots + {}&x^2y^{n-2} + {} & xy^{n-1}) & {} - {} &\\
&&(x^{n-1}y {}+{}& x^{n-2}y^2 +{}& \ldots + {} & x^2y^{n-2} + {}&  xy^{n-1} + {}& y^n)]&\\
=&x^n + {}&0+{}&0+{}&\ldots+{}&0+{}&0  &{}-y^n&\\
=& x^n - y^n
\end{array}
$$
That's my picture of how the algebra works.